MBA 2022 crashes with "DCP PANIC - No device added after powering on the rails"
My MacBook Air M2 2022 (16G, 512 GB SSD) crashes sporadically under certain circumstances. This happens for example when I accidentally move my external mouse after closing the lid. If an external monitor is connected, it turns back on and then the MacBook restarts after freezing. Afterwards, the error message reads:
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xfffffe00305392a8): DCP PANIC - ASSERT!AppleDCPDPTXPowerController.cpp:538 No device added after powering on the rails. HPD=0 - dcpav(27)
ASSERT!AppleDCPDPTXPowerController.cpp:538 No device added after powering on the rails. HPD=0
RTKit: RTKit-2419.120.45.release - Client: local-ipad14dcp.RELEASE

The cpu number varies.
This can be reliably reproduced by repeatedly hitting Esc on the login screen. The MacBook switches between hibernation and being awake and crashes after a few hits.
I have already

factory reset the MacBook,
reproduced the issue in safe mode and
reinstalled MacOS.

Even after these, the issue still occurs. Directly after the factory reset, without having anything external ever connected, the issue appears. This is therefore not related to the external monitor or external peripherals.
The current MacOS version is MacOS Sonoma 14.5. It also happened on 14.4. It is generally unclear when this started because, as mentioned above, it only happens sometimes.
Then, I have sent the MacBook in for repair to Apple since I was told this could be a hardware issue. In the report, it says that the "Logic Board" and "Touch ID" were replaced. But the issue is not fixed and I can still reproduce this.
For reference, on MacOS Sonoma 14.4, the message was:
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xfffffe0014798a1c): DCP PANIC - ASSERT!AppleDCPDPTXPowerController.cpp:538 No device added after powering on the rails. HPD=0 - dcpav(27)
ASSERT!AppleDCPDPTXPowerController.cpp:538 No device added after powering on the rails. HPD=0
RTKit: RTKit-2419.101.1.release - Client: local-ipad14dcp.RELEASE


Does this happen when the external monitor and mouse are disconnected? Have you tried connecting another external monitor (with a different cable) and another mouse?

@IconDaemon Yes, this also happens - even after the factory reset - with just the standalone MacBook which never has/had anything external connected.

In that case, is sending it back to Apple an option? They obviously didn't fix the issue yet.

@nohillside Yes, I will do that. But first, I want to figure out if I can maybe further diagnose the issue so I can maybe provide a hint as to what they were missing. Clearly, it was not the Logic Board that was the issue.

It seems as if Apple didn’t really fix it then. Hard to diagnose from where I sit.

Unfortunately, I'm unable to leave a comment due to my current reputation level. Have you tried running a hardware diagnostic? Additionally, DCP is related to the display, so there could be a display issue involved.

The result was: "No issues found"

Which external monitor do you have, and is it connected via thunderbolt? Do you have any USB devices connected to the Mac via the monitor's ports? If so, what devices are they? Do you have any other peripherals connected directly to your Mac?

@AndrewParks It was connected via the Apple USB-C to HDMI adapter, together with the external mouse and Keyboard (Logitech). However, this can be reproduced after the factory reset, without having anything external (ever) connected.

@schade96 Is the external mouse and keyboard wired or bluetooth? When you say it happens without "anything external" connected, does that mean not even the monitor? If it happens only with the monitor connected but not the keyboard/mouse, what action on the Macbook's internal keyboard/trackpad causes the crash?

@AndrewParks They are connected via a USB dongle. Yes, the monitor is not necessary here. It only helps to see that something has gone wrong. If it is not connected, you will see the issue only once you open the MacBook again. This is caused by any button press or touching (not necessarily pressing) the touchpad.

@schade96 So, you're saying that with no wired or wireless peripherals connected, including no monitor connected, the issue happens simply by opening the lid of the Macbook and lightly touching the Macbook's trackpad. I'd make that clear in your question, otherwise the question looks like this issue might be related to a problem with the monitor or peripherals.

I've also had this issue (on an M2 MacBook Air) in a similar way - I have the screen set to turn off after 2 minutes of inactivity, and when the screen turns off, if I immediately press a key to bring it back on, the laptop crashes on the spot - with the same error message.

I have received the MacBook back from Apple the second time. This time, they also replaced the display and the lid angle sensor. This seems to have fixed the issue. I can no longer trigger it by hitting Esc on the login screen. Additionally, the screen now also feels much more responsive when it comes to sleep mode and waking up. Before, there seems to have been a longer delay and now it is almost instantaneously.
So to summarize, this was indeed a hardware issue, most likely related to the display or the lid angle sensor or both.

Same experience for me. For future readers, try telling the technician at the Apple Store to include in the repair note that you cannot replicate the issue in clamshell mode. I was able to replicate the issue reliably by rapidly opening/closing the laptop lid repeatedly until it crashed. I tried to get Apple to replace the display + lid angle sensor the first time, but they first did the logic board + Touch ID and then did the display + lid angle sensor when the first repair failed. The Apple tech put "cannot replicate issue in clamshell mode" in the second repair note and I think that helped.
